# how to download content on PDF format on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom select query data and i want to export those data in to downloadable pdf
How can i do this?
Those selected query data changes according to the users. This data is like invoice
any idea about this?

I used below code but i can't open the pdf.

```
 $filename = "tender_report_" . date('Ymd') . ".pdf";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could you dynamically create a pdf within wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13133066/how-could-you-dynamically-create-a-pdf-within-wordpress)

Comment: Is the file already a PDF? If it's not, you need te create a PDF first using a tool like Dompdf https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf